# Why does Google Docs change the title of my doc to Chinese characters?

Tags: google-drive

When I open a pdf file from an email (happens on some but not all pdfs) Google Docs comes up with the correct title while showing the preview for my document.  Then a second later, it changes the title to Chinese.

This happens in both Firefox and Chrome.

Before:
[image]

After: [image]

Here's another example of English text:

JS 6.10.pdf - Powered by Google Docs

Here's the actual chinese it turns it into:

㽉㽮㽴㽵㽩㽴㽟㽑㽂㽏㽂㽟㽉㽮㽴㽥㽲㽮㽡㽬㼮㽰㽤㽦

Comment: Possibly an encoding issue? Do you see this in all browsers?

Comment: I'm seeing this also since today's morning. Strange.

Comment: Is it possible that Google is having a Geocoding issue currently?  It seems like Google is treating your computer like it is in a different country.

Comment: @randomben Adobe sometimes thinks I'm german for whatever reason.  Hrm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google is aware of the bug and will fix it shortly (or so they said on 7/26/10).
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=15406028a889cfe3&hl=en

Seems to be dependent on the PDF creator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing something similar. It appears there are two sections of the file that are not correctly encoded as UTF-8:

```
00003c0: 3c2f 7363 7269 7074 3e0a 0a0a 3c74 6974  </script>...<tit
00003d0: 6c65 3ee3 bd90 e3bd 8fe3 bd89 e3bd 8ee3  le>.............
00003e0: bd94 e3bc a0e3 bd84 e3bd afe3 bda3 e3bd  ................
00003f0: b5e3 bdad e3bd a5e3 bdae e3bd b420 2d20  ............. -
0000400: 506f 7765 7265 6420 6279 2047 6f6f 676c  Powered by Googl
0000410: 6520 446f 6373 3c2f 7469 746c 653e 0a3c  e Docs</title>.<


0003560: 2d6c 6566 7422 3e3c 6469 7620 636c 6173  -left"><div clas
0003570: 733d 2274 6974 6c65 2067 6f6f 672d 696e  s="title goog-in
0003580: 6c69 6e65 2d62 6c6f 636b 223e e3bd 90e3  line-block">....
0003590: bd8f e3bd 89e3 bd8e e3bd 94e3 bca0 e3bd  ................
00035a0: 84e3 bdaf e3bd a3e3 bdb5 e3bd ade3 bda5  ................
00035b0: e3bd aee3 bdb4 3c2f 6469 763e 0a3c 6469  ......</div>.<di
```

I haven't figured out what encoding it's intended to be yet.

Answer (score 1):

My Google account somehow changed languages and it took me forever to get a fix. Ultimately, I used a business account and got in touch with Google support (thank you Rodolfo!!), and he walked me through the solution. Here it is ... hope it helps!

1. USE Google Translate to read page and get into your account
2. Sign into Google account
3. go to Data & Customization (Personalization)
4. click on Globe icon ... then language
5. change language to English
6. then clear ALL cookies